# Confusion about linearity of expectation in Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, binomial-distribution

I was working through a basic example and realized that I'm might not be understanding the linearity of expectation properly. We have a coin that has probability $p$ of coming up heads and we flip this coin $N$ times. Let $r$ be the number of heads we get. It's a pretty standard result for binomial distributions that
$$<r>= {\rm Exp}(r)=Np\quad {\rm Var}(r) = Np(1-p)$$
And I understand how to get the expectation value of $r$ from linearity of expectation as well as the variance above from the linearity of variance for independent coin tosses. However I was also trying to get the variance in another way. We have
$${\rm Var}(r) = <r^2> - <r>^2$$
For a single coin toss we have $<r^2> = p(1^2) + (1-p)(0^2)$ and so by linearity of expectation we have for $N$ tosses $<r^2> = N p$ which gives us the variance
$${\rm Var}(r)= Np - N^2 p^2 = Np(1- Np)$$
Obviously something has gone wrong(I think in computing $<r^2>$) but I can't figure out what. Could someone nudge me towards whats' wrong?

Comment: Well, work it out for $N=2$.  There are $3$ possible values for $r$, the number of Heads.  Namely, $0,1,2$.  Easy to compute the probability for each, hence you can easily compute $E[r^2]$.  Does it match your value?

Comment: As a hint to see the error in what you wrote:  $(a+b)^2\neq a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Ok I think I see. So the coin flips in the context of $<r^2>$ are now dependent because of the cross term in $(a+b)^2$ and so you can't just sum $<r^2>$ for $N$ independent coins. Is there a way to use linearity of expectation to simplify computing $<r^2>$ then or am I reaching for nothing at this point?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.  There's really no great way to use linearity to compute Variance.  Try as you like, those cross terms just interfere.  There are, of course, situations in which you can manage the cross terms, but it's always a bit tricky.